# Zimbra mail server - Get Information about new incoming email

Tags: javascript, jsp, email, zimbra, zimlet

As you will all know that there are black list and white list in Zimbra mail server that will block or allow a new coming email. But it's quite inconvenient by this way to block an email. So I want to make a plugin in Zimbra mail server to filter email into spam and non spam category based on a list.

But the problem i met here is i can't get the information about a new incoming email address, here is email address and header. I've read some tutorials about writing a Zimlet, but it's all about making an action to get those information.

Can you guys tell me how to get those Information?

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't, what Zimlets are made for. Zimlets are extensions to the Web UI. Perhaps it's possible to write a server extension for that, though I don't know currently, if there's an extension class for that.

I would use a "milter" for that. A milter is a way of "hooking" into the mail delivery process.

For an example, have a look at my "disclaimr"-milter: https://github.com/dploeger/disclaimr

Inside the milter you would use the Zimbra SOAP-API to fetch objects from the Zimbra server (lists for example).

Comment: thank you for your information about soap-API. I can do it now with my Java-Soap-JSP program :)
So finally i realize i can't use something called zimlet here :(